# What is the difference between CCD and CDA

Tags: medical

What’s the difference between clinical document architecture (CDA) and Continuity of Care Document (CCD)? Having trouble understand what’s the difference and which one would be best to be used.

Comment: CCD appears to be a subset (not sure if that's the right word) of CDA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_of_Care_Document. Which one is "best" depends on what you need.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much!